# How to recover the navigation toolbar for a figure after it has been removed?

Tags: python, matplotlib

1. Figure 1. is displayed with some points in it.
2. When the user moves the mouse cursor near one
   of the points in Figure 1. and clicks the mouse
   button, an image (*.png file) specific to the 
   value of the selected point is displayed in a 
   new figure. Thus, each time a point is selected
   a new figure is created with a *.png file in
   it (e.g. Figure 2,3,...).

I do not wish to have a navigation toolbar
displayed in Figure 1. I was able to accomplish
this with the following statement:

```
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
```

Question -- How can I have a navigation toolbar
for Figure 2,3,... after it has been removed in
Figure 1.?

Answer (score 1):

When displaying the figures containing the images I used:

```
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolbar2' # to restore toolbar
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))  # for images
```

It was important to have this order in the statements; i.e., the mpl 
**before** the figure was defined.